# Is it possible to have Mercurial sent out an email to an address list as soon as someone has pushed to a certain repository?

Tags: email, mercurial

Or is this only possible by programming against the Mercurial API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [Mercurial Notify](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension) extension.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question...but do you really need to do this in Mercurial?
If your project/team has a certain size, you will probably have a build server. And most build servers can be configured so that they send mails after building.

At my workplace we are using Mercurial, and we have a build server running [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).
TeamCity monitors our Mercurial repositories, and everytime someone pushes to them, TeamCity pulls the code, compiles it and sends emails to the developers.

TeamCity is free for up to 20 users, easy to set up and it just works...so I never had to figure out how to make Mercurial send notification mails.